# Sorry, this site can't be saved as a template. It contains apps that don't work in templates

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, communication, sitetemplate

I have tried to save the SharePoint communication site as a template that contains apps. I have faced the below error.

Sorry, this site can't be saved as a template. It contains apps that don't work in templates.

Please check [social.technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fde6fd6-91e2-4110-8f03-aaa28d76f57b/sorry-this-site-cant-be-saved-as-a-template-it-contains-apps-that-dont-work-in-templates-modern?forum=onlineservicessharepoint) link for the same issue.

The above link suggests removing apps and saving the template of the site. But I will need a site template with apps. Can anyone suggest how to save SharePoint communication site as a template with apps?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this official article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/fails-saving-site-as-template

If the site contains apps that can't be saved as part of the template, it's necessary to remove any affected apps that are listed in the error message, and then save the site as a template.

If you want to use the app after you save the site as a template, you'll have to add it to the site again.

If you want to use the app in a new site based on template, you need to manually add it in the new site.